# Getting rows from mySql Descending from a certain point by php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently working on an app that request data from the sql server and showing it to the user.

when the data is showing the use can click back or next to see the next or previous data.

once the user received data the app cache it in local map to reduce calls to the server.
in order for the cashed data to work properly the app get the minimum and maximum Index of each row from the sql server.

there is a problem when a new data is inserted to the sql database while the user is browsing the app, because in that point the maximum id is changed so when the app request the new data, it evaluate the current max id that Index already have, the max Index represent the latest data, so the user might see duplicate rows.

the solution i thought of is restricting the rows that the sql server can retrieve by checking if the index value is smaller or equal to the cached max index value in the app, but i have no idea how to implement this.

**the question:**

how can i query the sql server to retrieve data only if the row field value is under a certain amount ?

**the code :**

```
$connect=mysqli_connect(HOST,USERNAME,PASSWORD,DB) or die ('error: '. mysql_error());

$MAXID = $_POST['MAX'];
$MINID = $_POST['MIN'];

$ORDERBY_TYPE = $_POST['TYPE'];
$LIMIT = $_POST['LIMIT'];
$OFFSET = $_POST['OFFSET'];

$ORDERBY = "";

$SKIP = false;

switch($ORDERBY_TYPE){
case 0:
    $ORDERBY = "ORDER BY RATING";
    //$ORDERBY = "WHERE VOTES > 5 ORDER BY RATING" <--- replace the upper line by this line some day
    break;
case 1:
    $ORDERBY = "ORDER BY ID";
    break;
case 2:
    $SKIP = true;
    break;
default:
    $ORDERBY = "ORDER BY ID";
}

$query = "";

if($SKIP)
{
//adding to the minimum id the amount needed to retrive
$MINID += $LIMIT;

//checking if there are more records then the amount needed <--- only in fresh start this is usefull
if($MINID<$MAXID)
{
    //getting a random id between the maximun id and the minimum id             after adding the amount needed
    $randomId = mt_rand($MINID,$MAXID);

    //setting offset to be skipped - that is the "distance" between the max id and the random id
    $OFFSET = $MAXID - $randomId;
    }
    else
{
   $OFFSET = 0; 
}
//getting the amount of records needed after skipping the "random" modefied value
$query = "SELECT * FROM `ugcl` ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT ". $LIMIT ." OFFSET ". $OFFSET ."";
}
else
{
$query = "SELECT * FROM `ugcl` ". $ORDERBY ." DESC LIMIT ". $LIMIT ." OFFSET ". $OFFSET ."";
}

$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);

if($result)
{    
$fields = array();

$col_query = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM `ugcl`";
$col_result = mysqli_query($connect,$col_query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($col_result)){
    array_push($fields, $row['Field']);
}

$fake_count = 0;

echo "[";
while ($array = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {

    echo "{";
    echo '"';
    echo $fake_count;
    echo '"';
    echo ":";
    echo "{";
    for($i = 0 ; $i < count($array) ; $i++){
        if($i > 0) echo ",";
        echo '"';
        echo $fields[$i];
        echo '"';
        echo ":";
        echo '"';
        echo $array[$i];
        echo '"';
    }
    echo "}";
    echo "},";
    $fake_count++;
}
 echo "]";
}
else
{
echo "error";   
}
```

Comment: Stop inventing wheel. There's `json_encode` function which does everything that you do in last __30__ lines.

Comment: @u_mulder  i tried json_encode but one of the field in each row is a json of over 1k chars and when i used json_encode it messed up the that field data and added "\" char every where, even after removing it i struggled formatting it in the right way in my app so i just did it my self. but thanks any way :)

Comment: Can you please clarify if your database is SQL Server or MySQL? and remove the tag that is not appropriate.

Comment: How is this any different than, say, Stackoverflow pagination. You are on page 4 (of n). You then go to 5 (or hop to m). In that routine, it re-jiggers appropriately for pagination having re-fetched the at the moment rowcount of the total pool, and re-calculates the offset.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to keep both max and min records count. just keep the latest record count as $offset and send it with $count as number of rows after it.

$offset is latest number of rows you have received before next request.

$count is how many rows you want from this query after offset.

query in sample will be:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`  order by `id` desc LIMIT $offset, $count
```

above query will give you the latest unique results without any duplicated rows.

if you do not want to modify your server code another idea is this: first cache the rows in app's local DB and then show them by fetch them from it with an query using "GROUP BY `server_id`" or use unique inserts instead of this.

keep things simple.